# Finstr get_xbrl_statement error parsing Extracted XBRL Instance Document

Tags: r, xbrl

Most recent AAPL 10-k XBRL Instance Document for example:

`doc <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019319000119/0000320193-19-000119-index.htm"`

## Run xbrlDoAll and xbrl_get_statements from XBRL and finstr packages, respectively

```
get_xbrl_doc <- xbrlDoAll(doc)
statements <- xbrl_get_statements(get_xbrl_doc)

Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 34 rows:
* 6, 8
* 5, 7, 9
* 49, 51
* 48, 50
* 55, 57
* 54, 56
* 11, 13
* 10, 12
* 25, 27
* 24, 26
* 59, 61
* 58, 60
* 29, 31
* 28, 30
* 63, 64, 66
* 62, 65
```

This sequence works perfectly up until 2019 when Apple switched to "Extracted XBRL Instance Document" from "XBRL Instance Document". Has anybody found a work around?

Answer (score 0):

Not only have they switched that, but now the fact ID brings some kind of 32-digit key that seems to have no connections with any of the other files in the taxonomy. This is probably related to the iXBRL process and I've seen it with another company as well.

However, if the problem is just the word "Extracted", then you just need to change the script, but I'm guessing this is not the case and the solution relates to finding out what those 32-digit keys mean.

I'm not an R user and I don't use Finstr, but I guess we have the same problem. So, the answer to your question would be: you need to write your own parser now or wait until someone finishes theirs.